# Problem while trying to start an ionic project

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, web-applications, ionic5

I have just installed npm and ionic following the instructions on ionic framework website and as soon as i start a new project i get these errors.
I have tried many online solutions but none seem to work.

```
npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has been deprecated in favor 
of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information. 
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...a512-0baf1FhCp16LhN+x'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Michel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-07T00_38_37_180Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: I downloaded the latest Node version from the website 12.18.0.

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Powershell as admin. Then run command:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and then install ionic again as usual:

```
ionic start
```

Comment: @Michel did you run it as admin? In your project directory?

Comment: Yes i did. I've tried a lot to get it to work i think i'm just going to move to another platform. Thank you for your effort.